# decode dictionary into array of codable structs

Tags: json, swift, codable

I have JSON as dictionary [String, Anyobject]:

```
{
  "AED": "United Arab Emirates Dirham",
  "AFN": "Afghan Afghani",
  "ALL": "Albanian Lek",
}
```

I need to decode it as array of codable structs Currency like:

```
struct Currency: Codable {
  var code: String
  var name: String
}

Currency(code: "AED", name: "United Arab Emirates Dirham")
```

Comment: I think that the question is fine, I don't know why some people vote negatively.

Answer (score 3):

You can decode the json as Dictionary and map to Array.

```
let currencies = try? JSONDecoder()
        .decode([String: String].self, from: data)
        .map({ Currency(code: $0.key, name: $0.value) })
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a container, for example named "Currencies" to use the single value container.

I share you the example playground:

```
let str = """
{
  "AED": "United Arab Emirates Dirham",
  "AFN": "Afghan Afghani",
  "ALL": "Albanian Lek",
}
"""

struct Currencies: Codable {
    var values: [Currency]

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let dict = try container.decode([String: String].self)

        values = dict.map({ (key, value) in
            return Currency(code: key, name: value)
        })
    }
}

struct Currency: Codable {
    var code: String
    var name: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case code
        case name
    }
}

let currencies = try JSONDecoder().decode(Currencies.self, from: Data(str.utf8))
print(currencies.values)
```